# Converting Hex coded timestamp into human readable dates

Tags: datetime, timestamp, hex

I've been working on some raw data obtained from a fingerprint machine(zkemkeeper/ZEM560). I found out that there is a sets of data written in hex and I believe it is a 4 bytes, little endian number of seconds from a certain date. Here some examples of the raw data  and expected date(got from GUI). My purpose is to get the expected date from the raw data.

```
Raw Data          Expected Date
E2 E8 24 26    2019-11-29 20:45:22
C9 1A 26 26    2019-11-30 18:30:33
44 A7 28 26    2019-12-01 16:54:28
3A 16 2A 26    2019-12-02 19:00:10

BD 5D 4C 26    2019-12-28 19:02:21
9F 0E 4F 26    2019-12-30 20:01:35
25 60 50 26    2020-12-31 20:01:41
12 03 53 26    2020-01-02 20:01:22

24 ED 77 26    2020-01-30 20:01:40
C2 3E 79 26    2020-01-31 20:02:10
21 82 7A 26    2020-02-01 19:01:53

46 D7 9C 26    2020-02-27 20:02:14
DE 28 9E 26    2020-02-28 20:02:38
A1 C0 A4 26    2020-03-02 20:03:45
32 12 A6 26    2020-03-03 20:04:02
```

Any method/suggestion can be used to convert this?

Comment: Which language can you use ?

Comment: i can use python @Marco

Comment: you are probably going to need a struct.unpack but do not know how

Comment: @Marco i dont really understand on the format of struct.unpack though. do you have any idea?

Comment: I tried this: s= b'\xe2\xe8\x24\x26'

print(len(s))
cur_time = struct.unpack('<I',s)
print(cur_time)
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(cur_time[0])
print(date).. I get something but not the date you want ..

Comment: @Marco thank you for that, I think it is a date difference from a certain date. when I try to get the expected date, it seems like the timestamp consider 31 days for every month. do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deciphering hex coded timestamp from a fingerprint machine (zkemkeeper/ZEM560)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828838/deciphering-hex-coded-timestamp-from-a-fingerprint-machine-zkemkeeper-zem560)